# Python TypeError: 'int' object is not callable in OOP

Tags: python, class, oop, int, setter

I have a problem. I learn of using `setters` in python. I have some code down here and I try to use method `measure_set` which doesn't work because I have a `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`. Can someon explain me why this is happens? I tried to find solution but I didin't find a similar problem in OOP with using setters. Thanks, and have a nice day.

```
class Sensor:
    def __init__(self, location, _measurement = 0, _precision = float('inf'), _unit = 'N/A'):
        self._measurement = _measurement
        self._precision = _precision
        self._unit = _unit
        self.location = location
        self.log = []

    @property
    def log_average(self):
        return sum(self.log)/len(self.log)

    @property
    def measurement(self):
        return self._measurement

    @measurement.setter
    def measure_set(self, measure):
        self._measurement = measure
        self.log.append(self._measurement)

    @property
    def description(self):
        return f'{self._measurement} +/- {self._unit}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Sensor('Ostatni Grosz')
    print(s.description)
    s.measure_set(10)
    s.measure_set(20)
    print(s.log)
    print(s.log_average)
```

Comment: The name of your setter has to match the original property.

Comment: I know, so that is happening. `@measurement.setter` has name like `measurement` property

Comment: That's not the setter; that's the decorator that *sets* the setter for the property *measurement*. The setter is the function you are decorating.

Comment: Ok, I understand know. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the setter should match the name of the property.

```
@measurement.setter
def measurement(self, measure):
    self._measurement = measure
    self.log.append(self._measurement)
```

because the `property` instance returned by `measurement.setter` is assigned to the name `measurement`. With your code, you now have two separate properties, one (read-only) property named `measurement` and one named `measurement_set`.

The setter isn't meant to be called directly (and can't, because the name no longer refers to a callable object, but to the property).  When you write `self.measurement_set(10)`, the attribute access `self.measurement_set` returns (via the getter) the current `int` value of `self._measurement`, then tries to call that with an argument of 10.

Instead, you just assign to the property directly, which triggers the invocation of the setter.

```
s.measurement = 10
s.measurement = 20
```

Comment: Aaa, ok. I knew that but I didn't do this that way. I don't know why. Thanks man.

Comment: For a long time, I thought using the same name for the setter was just a convention.